# OWLREADY 2 cannot load ontology if it uses different namespace

Tags: owlready

The problem arises with the Blondie ontology. If I download the ontology and try to load it with OWLReady 2, I get the following error:

```
   raise OwlReadyOntologyParsingError("RDF/XML parsing error in file %s, line %s, column 
  %s." % (getattr(f, "name", getattr(f, "url", "???")), parser.CurrentLineNumber, 
 parser.CurrentColumnNumber)) from e
   owlready2.base.OwlReadyOntologyParsingError: RDF/XML parsing error in file 
   https://www.afternic.com:443/forsale/semanticblockchain.com? utm_source=TDFS_DASLNC&utm_medium=DASLNC&utm_campaign=TDFS_DASLNC&traffic_type=TDFS_DASLNC&traffic_id=daslnc&, line 28, column 395.
```

The problem seems to be related with the namespace of the ontology, namely "http://www.semanticblockchain.com/Blondie.owl" which is unavaible, but apparently OWLReady tries to load the ontology from that source. How I can get rid of such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

calling the method load(only_local=True) of an ontology seems to do the trick.

Comment: could you edit your answer to reflect to which function/method the option has to be passed?

Comment: Answer modified as requested

Comment: And how do we need to define the owl:imports statement? Does not work for me!

Comment: Is the import statement inside the ontology?